# Last 24 Hours Data Report Show In Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, loops, chart.js

Last 24 hours data Report show..
If the report has not been created within an hour,zero inserted default.

My Query:

```
 $dayReport = Report::select(DB::raw("HOUR(created_at) as hourNo,SUM(site_id) as count"))
                        ->where('site_id',$site->id)
                        ->whereDate('created_at','>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(24))
                        ->orderBy("created_at")
                        ->groupBy(DB::raw("hour(created_at)"))
                        ->get()
                        ->toArray();
```

Output Like this:

```
  data: [0,2,4,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,6,7,0,8,0,6,10,22]
```

My Output is:

```
  data: [2,4,2,2]
```

This is Chart Js Data in Javascript 0 default value within 1 hour not report create.

Thank you in Advance...

Comment: In this example you should avoid `groupBy` statement. Group by will not take all `0`  and if there are multiple records of 2, 4 then it will only take single record. Also please give hour column to default value `0`. So when record will insert without anything then it will take default to zero.

Comment: can you please share your table structure?

Comment: Running a Loop ... Last 24 Timer's Timestamp@MayankDudakiya

Comment: Running a Loop ... Last 24 Timer's Timestamp@Shibon

Comment: Not a Table Structure In use..@Shibon

Answer (score 1):

From the query you will get hour and sum  if so.. you can try the bellow code

```
$results = array(array('hour' => 2, 'count' => 3), array('hour' => 3, 'count' => 3), array('hour' => 13, 'count' => 10));
$hours = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13); //up to 24
$finalResult = [];
 foreach($hours as $hour){
    $hourSearch = array_search($hour, array_column($results, 'hour')); 
   if(is_numeric($hourSearch)) {
    //  array_push($finalResult, $results[$hourSearch]);
    array_push($finalResult,$results[$hourSearch]['count']);
   } else {
   //   $data['hour'] = $hour;
   //  $data['count'] = 0;
   //array_push($finalResult, $data);
    array_push($finalResult,0);
  }
}

echo json_encode($finalResult);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3c04e3b58b01b9f70652a3398379d867453b0ea

Answer (score 1):

i have read the answer by **@Shibon** and its looks good

i have a Same Situation while creating the charts based on 
https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts

So I have created the function for it

Here is my array only with values but i need to set the other values to zero so i have created my own function

```
 $arrayWithValues = 
                        [
                            '02' => '20',
                            '09' => '45',
                            '15' => '68',
                            '21' => '28'
                        ];

 $defaultEmptyArray = [
                        '00' => '0',
                        '01' => '0',
                        '02' => '0',
                        '03' => '0',
                        '04' => '0',
                        '05' => '0',
                        '06' => '0',
                        '07' => '0',
                        '08' => '0',
                        '09' => '0',
                        '10' => '0',
                        '11' => '0',
                        '12' => '0',
                        '13' => '0',
                        '14' => '0',
                        '15' => '0',
                        '16' => '0',
                        '17' => '0',
                        '18' => '0',
                        '19' => '0',
                        '20' => '0',
                        '21' => '0',
                        '22' => '0',
                        '23' => '0',
                    ];
```

Now we need to replace the array only that has the value and i have written my own function

```
function setUnsettedArray($actulHourWithValue = [] ,$defaultEmptyArray = [])
{
    $arraNotExists = [];

     foreach ($defaultEmptyArray as $defKey => $defValue) 
        {
            if (array_key_exists($defKey, $actulHourWithValue)) 
            {
                $arrayEXists[] = [$defKey => $actulHourWithValue[$defKey]];
            }
            elseif (!array_key_exists($defKey, $actulHourWithValue)) 
            {
                $arraNotExists[] =  [$defKey => $defValue];
            }
        }

        $newArray = array_merge($arraNotExists,$arrayEXists);


        foreach ($newArray as $newKey => $newValue) 
        {
            $keys[] = $newKey;
            foreach ($newValue as $key => $value) 
            {
                $allKesy[] = $key;
                $allValues[] = $value;
            }

        }

        $finalArray = array_combine($allKesy,$allValues);
        ksort($finalArray);

        return $finalArray;    
}
```

and try to pass the array as  `print_r(setUnsettedArray($arrayWithValues,$defaultEmptyArray));`

and here is the fiddle for it

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/sfq3-adyn

I have EDITED the `setUnsettedArray` function

```php
function setUnsettedArray(array $arrayWithValues ,array $defaultArray)
{
        $finalArray = $arrayWithValues+$defaultArray;
        ksort($finalArray);
        return $finalArray;    
}
```

And i have seen Your Query and its not to good

So try this

```
$lastTwentyFour =  Report::where('site_id','=',$site->id)
                        ->whereDate('created_at', '=', Carbon::now()->subHours(24))
                        ->orderBy('created_at')
                        ->get()
                        ->groupBy(function($date) 
                                    {
                                    return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('H');
                                    }
                                );
```

and You can count the each hour collection as

```
foreach ($lastTwentyFour as $newGroupByKey => $newGroupByValue) 
        {
            $eachHour[] = $newGroupByKey;
            $eachHourCount[] = $newGroupByValue->count();
        }


$actulHourWithValue = array_combine($eachHour,$eachHourCount);
```

Comment: example for, 1 am in not report create default 0 created in chartjs.. 2 am report created 16 in chart js...24 hours report show in chartjs @Manojkiran.A

Comment: do you want in 12 hrs way??

Comment: can You please `dd()` the `$lastTwentyFour`  var and show the result

Comment: the result is : `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,7,0,0,0,3,0,0,1,4]` example result... My output is generally not same output..

Comment: please see the screenshot attached here https://i.imgur.com/m1jtQRN.png  in this the number `16` denotes `4PM` are you getting like this.Please do attach the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191020/discussion-between-manojkiran-a-and-smit-pipaliya).

Answer (score 1):

I dont seem to understand your question exactly but using carbon would help alot when it comes to working with dates, it would reduce your code by a lot of lines. 
`$now = Carbon\Carbon::now;
 $hoursBefore = $now->subDays(1);

$reports = Report::where('site_id', $site->id)->whereBetween('created_at', [$hoursBefore, $now])->get()->toArray();
`

I hope this helps.
Thanks, good luck and Happy coding.... :)

Comment: what response are you getting?

Comment: `[2,2,4]` geetting result